# .net standard library fails in .net core but not in framework

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, garbage-collection, .net-standard

We have to use api from 3rd party vendor(perforce). Till today, we were able to reference and use that API  in .net framework application. But, now we are refactoring our product and of course we decided to use new .net environment, which is .net core 2.2. As, Perforce didn't publish that library for .net core, we decided to port that library to .net standard.

So, in a nutshell we downloaded source code, ported, and added as a reference in .net core project.

So far, so good.  A weird thing is that, after some usage of that library we are getting [`ExecutionEngineException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.executionengineexception?view=netframework-4.8) from that library, which triggers `Environment.Failfast` and terminates application.

One more important information is that library uses another native library(p4bridge.dll).

The exception is so:

```
FailFast:
A callback was made on a garbage collected delegate of type 'p4netapi!Perforce.P4.P4CallBacks+LogMessageDelegate::Invoke'.

   at Perforce.P4.P4Bridge.RunCommandW(IntPtr, System.String, UInt32, Boolean, IntPtr[], Int32)
   at Perforce.P4.P4Bridge.RunCommandW(IntPtr, System.String, UInt32, Boolean, IntPtr[], Int32)
   at Perforce.P4.P4Server.RunCommand(System.String, UInt32, Boolean, System.String[], Int32)
   at Perforce.P4.P4Command.RunInt(Perforce.P4.StringList)
   at Perforce.P4.P4CommandResult..ctor(Perforce.P4.P4Command, Perforce.P4.StringList)
   at Perforce.P4.P4Command.Run(Perforce.P4.StringList)
   at Perforce.P4.Client.runFileListCmd(System.String, Perforce.P4.Options, System.String, Perforce.P4.FileSpec[])
   at Perforce.P4.Client.SyncFiles(System.Collections.Generic.IList`1<Perforce.P4.FileSpec>, Perforce.P4.Options)
```

I am already aware of the message related to `garbage collected delegate`. It seems, at some place pointer to the delegate is passed to unmanaged library and then GC collected it.

We take a look to the source code of that api. And we saw some possible places which can be reason for that error. But, this is just a thought.

While investigating the failure, we created another .net framework application which references to that ported library, and ***then we didn't came across any error in .net framework.***

My questions are:

1. ***Is there any difference between .net framework and .net core in terms of garbage collector mechanism***?
2. ***How is that possible that, .net framework and .net core reacts to the same library in a different ways?***

Comment: "Is there any difference between .net framework and .net core in terms of garbage collector mechanism?" - absolutely! the GC has continued to evolve; however, I *suspect* that if it was working previously, the most likely scenario is that it was working by accident in an "undefined behavior" way; can you provide any more specifics about how this callback was shared with the other library?

Comment: "How is that possible that, .net framework and .net core reacts to the same library in a different ways?" - because the JIT, GC, and BCL have all undergone significant amount of changes; a lot code won't be adversely affected, but some scenarios: absolutely! heck, even something as simple as asking "what is the 'default' text encoding?" (where 'default' is absolutely the wrong word) is fundamentally different...

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks for the information. Actually, we found one place where they are passing pointer to the unmanaged library, and at some point they are reinitializing that variable inside .net api.  Actually, after investigating source code, we found it weird how it works in .net framework.

Comment: in reality, if you're passing pointers to unmanaged code, it is *incredibly* easy to produce code that is simply broken; all the "simple" options are only well-defined for the duration of a single P/Invoke call, or for the duration of a `fixed` block; for most long-lived scenarios, you need to deal with manual pins via `GCHandle`, etc; it is **very** easy for that kind of P/Invoke code to be wrong. So: if it is wrong, we're again in undefined territory, where wrong code can "work" for small values of "work"; it won't amaze me for this kind of code to be brittle over framework switches

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I thought to post answer to my question as I already solved the issue. And as you are reading my answer now it means that you have faced with a similar problem. First of all, I want to thank to [@MarcGravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) for his comments and recommend to you to read the comments.

At first, want to summarize answer to the 2nd question:

> ***How is that possible that, .net framework and .net core reacts to the
>   same library in a different ways?***

To be honest, from the first glance I was thinking that .net standard library will behave itself in a same manner everywhere. But, of course I was wrong.

Let's start by "defintion" of `.Net Standard`. `.NET Standard` is nothing but ***a specification (think of it as an Interface)***,  it just only declares what types and APIs are exposed by a specific platform depending on is version.

If you will take a look, you will see that your standard library references the .NET Standard SDK that contains a `netstandard.dll` containing the APIs or, to better say, the ***contract***, we can use from within the library project. If you will take a look, to the your standard library with `Ildasm.exe`, you will see that it is using `.netstandard.dll`.

[image]

And let's check how it is used by our core and framework apps. And in core it works better than framework.

I am always a fan of diagrams:

[image]

As you see in the diagram, both core and framework apps reference ***their own*** `netstandard.dll`. And those libraries are built based on the `type forwarding`concept. 
For core apps, `BCL` types are  provided by `System.Runtime.dll`, while in case of framework apps `BCL`types are provided by `mscorlib.dll`. So, ***two different implementations***.

For example, here is the IL code of `.netstandard` library which will be used by core apps:

[image]

Read more about [type forwarding from msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/type-forwarding?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

[Source](https://medium.com/corrado-cavalli/hownetstandardwork-a6fdcd0adff8) of details about `.NET Standard`.

---

**And now a bit regarding to my first question:**

> ***Is there any difference between .net framework and .net core in terms
>   of garbage collector mechanism?***

Actually it must not be surprise that Microsoft continues to evolve GC mechanism.

---

**And now how I solved the issue:**

Good thing was that library which I ported to standard was open source. I investigated the issue, and in a nutshell they are passing delegate pointer to the unmanaged library. And that unmanaged library saves the pointer and tries to use it during some lifetime which is longer that the lifetime of that pointer. Actually, the interesting point is that framework GC is not collecting that delegate somehow and that's why no exception in framework side. But, in case of core GC collects that delegate and creates reason to the failure.  I did change the way how I set that field and it works now. I declared that field as static and initialize it inside static constructor, so lifetime of that delegate is as long as app lifetime.

Comment: I'm really pleased that you got to the bottom of that!

Comment: Since GC is not deterministic, it's reasonably common for bugs like this to go undiscovered for a long time.

Comment: Thank you so much for this post and it's answer.  You obviously spent a lot of time on this.   

One Request...  As the current maintainer of P4API.NET I am very interested in knowing exactly what changes you had to make to fix this issue,  so I can incorporate them into the next release.  

Could you make your source code changes available?  Much Thanks!